# yakuake on all screens

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, console

I've got a laptop with linux/ubuntu and I attach it to an external monitor or to a projector. I want my [yakuake](https://yakuake.kde.org/) to be shown on all screens, i.e. my laptop screen and the external device. So far I have found only an option to choose the screen:

- at mouse position
- screen 1
- screen 2

but I can't see an option to display the same yakuake on all screens. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

At this date (2018-10-30)

Yakuake it has that option in configuration, just turn on:

- Show in all desktops
- At mouse position <- this one is excellent!

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if you use windows but if you do, maybe this will help you.

You can choose to mirror, or duplicate, your desktop on all displays. A mirrored desktop—the default display option—is useful if you plan to use your mobile PC to give a presentation on a projector or a fixed display in a conference room, such as a wall-mounted plasma display or TV-type monitor.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/understanding-multiple-monitors

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not using windows.

Comment: Don't you mean luckily ;) Found this: Report bugs and wishes at: https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=yakuake Maybe you can ask the developer directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yakuake won't be able to open on any other screens but the primary when using Wayland.
If one uses the old x.org display protocol instead, it works a lot better.
Wayland is still far from ready to be used in everyday tasks.